# How to access files on second HHD

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive

I'm using a VM with Ubuntu installed. An old VM wont boot anymore, but trying to retrieve some files off of it. I set up a new small VM with its own hard drive and installed Ubuntu on it. I then mounted the old VMs HHD to it. I can view that the VM see's the old harddrive, but I'm new to Ubuntu and not sure how to access any files contained on it (or even if I can).

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want to mount /dev/sdb1 which has an existing LVM volume on it. I don't have a system with LVM at the moment so don't want to tell you anything I can't verify - but you could try googling "ubuntu mount existing LVM volume"

Comment: Thanks. That lead me to this article and it worked like a charm. 

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-an-lvm-volume-partition-command/